# Question on a learnpython.org excercise on loops (complete novice)

Tags: python

https://www.learnpython.org/en/Loops

Hello I am a complete novice to coding and a friend recommended this site to me to learn python.
I am having trouble understanding what I am doing wrong in the exercise in the link above.

The exercise is as follows:

Exercise
Loop through and print out all even numbers from the numbers list in the same order they are received. Don't print any numbers that come after 237 in the sequence.

SCRIPT

```
numbers = [
    951, 402, 984, 651, 360, 69, 408, 319, 601, 485, 980, 507, 725, 547, 544,
    615, 83, 165, 141, 501, 263, 617, 865, 575, 219, 390, 984, 592, 236, 105, 942, 941,
    386, 462, 47, 418, 907, 344, 236, 375, 823, 566, 597, 978, 328, 615, 953, 345,
    399, 162, 758, 219, 918, 237, 412, 566, 826, 248, 866, 950, 626, 949, 687, 217,
    815, 67, 104, 58, 512, 24, 892, 894, 767, 553, 81, 379, 843, 831, 445, 742, 717,
    958, 609, 842, 451, 688, 753, 854, 685, 93, 857, 440, 380, 126, 721, 328, 753, 470,
    743, 527
]

# your code goes here
```

and I wrote:

```
count=0
while(numbers[count]!=237):
    if(numbers[count]%2==1):
        count +=1
        continue
    print(numbers[count])
    count +=1
```

for the code section, and the output was :

output:
    402
    984
    360
    408
    980
    544
    390
    984
    592
    236
    942
    386
    462
    418
    344
    236
    566
    978
    328
    162
    758
    918

which I am pretty sure fits the goal of the exercise. 
However, the site keeps displaying the following red message,

"Define a object number using the code from the tutorial to print just the desired numbers from the exercise description."

which, in my understanding, means that my answer is somehow wrong. What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Apparently they want you to call the index variable `number` rather than `count`. But I'm absolutely positive that isn't the answer they were after anyway; you are certainly supposed to use a `for` loop.

Comment: I guessed that since the lesson included for, if, while, and else, and since they did not specify that I had to use a specific one, any combination of what were in the lesson would make for a correct answer. I will try using for loop thanks!